# How Do you export only R code from Rnw file

Tags: latex, ess, r

I am working with knitr, polymode, ess and I would like to export just the R code from my .Rnw into a .R file. A basic file might look something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

My Rnw file 

<<>>=
##This is some R code 
1+1 
@

\end{document}
```

In the end, I would like an R file with just

```
##This is some R code
1+1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, [*tangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) is implemented via `knitr::purl` and `utils::Stangle`.

ESS provides an interface to these commands.  See the variable `ess-swv-processor` and the `ess-swv-weave` function (bound to <kbd>M-n</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> in `Rnw-mode`).